# AdventureWorks & AdventureWorks2005

Tags: sql

I have downloaded and installed Microsoft SQL server Management Studio Express SQLServer 2005. I could not find AdventureWorks databases in it. Do i suppose to download and install it as well? If so, could someone point me to the site where i can download AdventureWorks and its instruction? Once again, I am using Microsoft SQL server Management Studio Express 2005.

Many thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 3):

The database is not part of the installation.

For Express and CE you need to download and install: [SQL Server 2005 Samples and Sample Databases](http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/)